# It's not validating the user

Tags: php, email, passwords

I am trying to write a code which can validate user by checking details in database. following is my script:

```
<?php

$DB_NAME='learning';
$DB_PASS='';
$DB_HOST='localhost';
$DB_USER='root';

$link=mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);

if(!$link)
{die('Couldnt connect');
}

$db_select=mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_select)
{die('Couldnt connect');
}

$EMAIL=$_POST['email'];
$PASS=md5($_POST['pass']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM form WHERE email='$EMAIL' and 'password'='$PASS'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    echo "Login Success!! ";
else
    echo "Wrong email or Password ";
?>
```

it's showing WRONG EMAIL or PASSWORD every time.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your this line:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM form WHERE email='$EMAIL' and 'password'='$PASS'";
```

you have added `''` to field name.

**Side Note**:
Also please try to avoid **mysql**

Comment: Jigar Shah,

Sorry for stupid question! Thanks though! 
 and what do you mean by "AVOID MYSQL" ? what else?

Comment: you can use PDO (recommended) or mysqli